# How do you reverse/capitalize words in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a python function which capitalizes every even word within a string sentence, and also reverses every odd word within that string.
For example:

aString = "Michelle ma belle these are words that go together well"

bString = "MICHELLE am BELLE eseht ARE sdrow THAT og TOGETHER llew "

I have a VERY basic understanding of how to do this but not really.

Here is what I have so far...

```
def RewordProgram(a):
    L = input("enter a sentence, please")
    if L[0:][::2]:                  # for even words
        b = L.upper()
        return b  
    else if L[1:][::2]:              # for odd words
        c = L[::-1] 
        return c
```

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong? The if else function isn't working for me, and I have no idea how of how to re-compile b and c into a new string. Is that even possible?

Comment: I added more comments about your original code. Also repeating that ``print`` is your friend here!

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are looking at single characters, not words. `L` is a string, so you need to use `split()` to get the words. It's always a good idea to print out as much as possible if you are new to a problem. Printing the value of `L[0:]` and `L[0:][::2]` would be very helpful and something that tells you what path the execution takes.

`L[0:][::2]` actually just returns every second character of the entire string. `L[0:]` is the same as `L` since it creates a string from index 0 to the end of the string... then `[::2]` skips every second character.

`print` is your friend! .. maybe combined with using a debugger, but prints will also do the job.

You can solve the problem with a generator expression:

```
text = "Michelle ma belle these are words that go together well"
r = ' '.join(w[::-1] if i % 2 else w.upper() for i, w in enumerate(text.split()))
print(r)
```

The verbose version of this would be (less scary):

```
words = []
for i, w in enumerate(text.split()):
    # odd
    if i % 2:
        words.append(w[::-1])
    else:
        words.append(w.upper())
print(" ".join(words))
```

Also note the use of `enumerate` that will return an `(index, value)` tuple for each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

A fundamental rule in computer science is breaking problems down into subproblems. In your case, I recommend that you start by breaking the solution to the problem into several functions:

- `words` that takes the string as an argument and returns a list of words contained in it.
- `upcase` that returns a string in upper case.
- `reverse` that reverses a string.

Once you've wrote these functions you'll need some other function to glue the pieces together. You'll need:

- A way to add an index to each word in a list of words (hint: `enumerate`).
- A way to apply a procedure to each item in a list of words with indexes (hint: `map`).

I've included complete code below. I recommend you don't read it right away but use it as a help when you're stuck at one of the steps above.

## Spoiler Alert: Solution Below

```
# This function reverses the word. It's a bit tricky: reversed returns an    
# enumerator representing a sequence of individual characters. It must be    
# converted into a string by joining these characters using an empty string. 
def reverse(string):                                                         
    '''Reverse a string.'''                                                  
    return ''.join(reversed(string))                                         

# Upcasing is simpler. Normally, I would've inlined this method but I'm leaving
# it here just to make it easier for you to see where upcasing is defined.   
def upcase(string):                                                          
    '''Convert the string to upcase.'''                                      
    return string.upper()                                                    

# Normally, I'd use the split function from the re module but to keep things 
# simple I called the split method on the string and told it to split the string
# at spaces.                                                                 
def words(string):                                                           
    '''Return a list of words in a string.'''                                
    return string.split(' ')                                                 

# This is your function. It works as follows:                                
#                                                                            
# 1. It defines an inner function _process_word that takes the index of the word
#    and the word itself as arguments. The function is responsible for       
#    transforming a single word.                                             
# 2. It splits the string into words by calling words(string).               
# 3. It adds a zero-based index to each of the words with enumerate.         
# 4. It applies _process_word to each and every item of the sequence in 3.   
# 5. It joins the resulting words with spaces.                               
def capitalize_and_reverse(string):                                          
    def _process_word((index, word)):                                        
        if index % 2 == 0:                                                   
            return upcase(word)                                              
        else:                                                                
            return reverse(word)                                             

    return ' '.join(map(_process_word, enumerate(words(string))))            


string = "Michelle ma belle these are words that go together well"           
print capitalize_and_reverse(string)                                         
# MICHELLE am BELLE eseht ARE sdrow THAT og TOGETHER llew
```